# how to validate org.w3.dom.Document over xsd?

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd

I convert String to org.w3.dom.Document in the following piece of code:

```
public static Document convertStringToDocument(String xmlSource) 
        throws SAXException, ParserConfigurationException, IOException{
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        return builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlSource)));
}
```

How can I validate it over xsd like I do with JAXBSource here.

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Test.class);
        JAXBSource source = new JAXBSource(jc, ga2);

        SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new File("my.xsd"));

        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        validator.setErrorHandler(new MyErrorHandler());
        //validator.validate(source);

        validator.validate(new DOMSource(ConnectureXmlParser.convertStringToDocument("<test>Test</test>")));
```

So it works fine with JAXBSource from my class, but it doesn't work with Document type. 
What should I do in order to validate my org.w3c.dom.Document over the same xsd ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to call `setNamespaceAware(true)` on your instance of `DocumentBuilderFactory` if your XML had namespaces.